# I would like to make a thread safe for long values

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, performance, java-8

I have a scheduled method with integer values with conditions and also have long values for checking these conditions, My code is working however I would like to make a thread safe for long values, I have found AtomicInteger but I do not know how to apply on my code;

My code below;

Yaml file;

```
  listenForInfo: 20000
  listenForWarn: 30000
  listenForError: 40000
  listenScheduled: 1000
```

My main code;

```
    @Value("${listenForInfo}")
    private int listenForInfo;

    @Value("${listenForWarn}")
    private int listenForWarn;

    @Value("${listenForError}")
    private int listenForError;
    
    private long lastReceivedMessage = System.nanoTime();

    

  @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topic}'}", groupId = "#{'${kafka.groupid}'}")
public void consume(String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partition,
                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset, Acknowledgment ack) {

    logger.info("offset = {} ", offset);
    logger.info("partition = {} ", partition);
    logger.info("kafka Message  : {}", message);

    lastReceivedMessage = System.nanoTime();

    try {
        service.processMessage(message, ack, null);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
   

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${listenScheduled}", initialDelay = 1000)
    private void distanceBetweenLastReceivedMessageAndCurrentTime() {

      long  currentTime = (System.nanoTime() - lastReceivedMessage) / 1000000;

        logger.info("current time : {}", currentTime);

        if (currentTime >= listenForInfo && currentTime < listenForWarn) {
            EventUtil.publishEvent("event info ", EventSeverityStatus.INFO, EventTypeStatus.CUSTOM, null);
    
        }

        if (currentTime >= listenForWarn && currentTime < listenForError) {
            EventUtil.publishEvent("event warn ", EventSeverityStatus.WARN, EventTypeStatus.CUSTOM, null);

        
        }

        if (currentTime >= listenForError) {
            EventUtil.publishEvent("event error ", EventSeverityStatus.ERROR, EventTypeStatus.CUSTOM, null);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Need more explanation for 

> I would like to make a thread safe for long values

Comment: There's also AtomicLong, if that's of any help.

Comment: Hello, Nikolai there is Atomic but how can I apply for my code can you write it please

Comment: what is the problem you're trying to solve? I don't think using AtomicInteger or AtomicLong will fix anything here

Comment: Is there any reason why `currentTime` is not a local variable?

Comment: @holger I want to use currentTime inside two method , that is the reason so how can ı cnage it

Comment: @eis I just want to make my application thread safe

Comment: So you expect answers regarding the thread safety of your program, without showing the relevant parts?

Comment: I have edit my code

Comment: take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html

Comment: @Holger thank you for your suggestion my latest code above

Comment: also how can ı simply my schedule insted of using a lot of zero is there any way like using hours on yml ?